# ¿Cómo puedo iniciar un activity desde un fragment?

Tags: java, android-studio

```Java
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_principal, null);



    }
```

ese es el código del fragment, pero me da error al tratar de hacerlo con un intent y trate haciendolo en el MainActivity pero colapsa la aplicación. Ayuda.

Los fragments estan en el MainActivity ya que los use para hacer un menú.

Ayuda

Comment: Puedes poner el Inten que haces? no deberia dar problema7

Comment: Eso intento, lo haré con un intent pero tratare de cambiar el formato

Comment: *El método a ver que pasa

Comment: que error marca el logcat?

Comment: Cannot resolve the symbol view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer un `Intent` desde un fragment:

```
 @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_principal, container, false);

    TextView tv = v.findViewById(R.id.textview)

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Eso he hecho pero necesito que encuentre un TextView que esta en el XML y es ahí donde da el error porque el método normal de "findViewById" no parece servir en este caso

Comment: Pero ese debes especificarlo en tu pregunta

Comment: Tienes razón, procuraré hacerlo a la otra

Comment: Pero como puedo resolver eso